# constructing CGGeometry in Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures

In Objective C, one can use the C struct syntax to create a CGRect:

```
CGRect aRect = { aPoint, aSize };
CGRect aRect = { {aPoint.x, aPoint.y}, aSize };
CGrect aRect = { aPoint, {aSize.width, aSize.height} };
CGRect aRect = { {aPoint.x, aPoint.y}, {aSize.width, aSize.height} };
```

Does Swift provide something similar?

Comment: I think you can call CGRectMake et. al. from Swift

Comment: This is not "Objective-C shortcuts"; this is C struct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there are no shorthands for `CGRect` in swift. The existing function seems short enough already.

```
let rect = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to use a CGRect constructor. There are several:

```
init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double)
init(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int)
```

i.e.

```
let r = CGRect(x: 1, y: 2, width: 3, height: 4)
```